# SQLAlchemy Filter for object in list

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to do a particular query with SQLAlchemy and I'm having some difficulty.

Let me explain the background a little:

A Box has a Permission associated with it. A User must have the appropriate permission to view the Box.
I'm trying to get all the Boxes where the current user (`api_call['user']`) has the Permission to view. ie. The Boxes who's Permission is in the User.permissions list. 
I'm also doing a check to ensure the box is in the user's company.

Here's the query:

```
result = Box.query.filter(and_(Box.company_id == api_call['user'].user_type.company_id, Box.permission in api_call['user'].permissions)).all()
```

But this part isn't working:

```
Box.permission in api_call['user'].permissions
```

The error suggests using .contains() (which I've tried and failed with).

Can anyone help me out?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you should do `Box.permission.in_(api_call['user'].permissions)` instead. This should work assuming `Box.permission` is a mapped attribute, and `api_call['user'].permissions` is a list of values.